# Thick border on some ParametricPlot3D objects

Tags: plotting

Object `x` should be composed of thick lines, object `su` should have no or a thin border.

With `BoundaryStyle`, I am not able to differentiate between `x` and `su`. I haven't had much luck with `PlotStyle -> {Thick, }` or `PlotStyle -> {EdgeForm[Thick], }` either.

```
x1 := {u, 0, 0}
x2 := {u, 1, 1}
x3 := {0, w, w}
x4 := {1, w, w}
x := {x1, x2, x3, x4}
su := {u, (1 - u) w^2 + u w^2, (1 - u) w + u w}
ParametricPlot3D[{x, su}, {u, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since your `x`'s are just lines, why not just render them as separate primitives (i.e. with `Line[]`) and then combine them with your surface using `Show[]`?

Comment: To be precise, did you want something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LaRlF.png)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, exactly like this. However, `x1`-`x4` do not necessarily have to be straight lines, they can also be functions that meet in the corners.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to invoke `ParametricPlot3D[]` twice; once for your surface, and once for your curves, and then combine all that with `Show[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "lines" or edges of 3D plots are not controlled by `PlotStyle` (as one might think from 2D experience), but by `BoundaryStyle`. Since this is applied to all objects in the plot, I suggest plotting them one at a time and combining with `Show`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[#, {u, 0, 1}, {w, 0, 1}, BoundaryStyle -> #2, Mesh -> None] & @@@ 
    {{x, Directive[Red, Thick]}, {su, None}} // Show
```

[image]

Comment: It somehow seems perverse to me that `BoundaryStyle` affects curves, seeing that they don't really have a boundary... :)

Comment: @J.M. I agree, and this used to trip me up quite often in the past.